# iOS : Use of class template 'ReadValues' requires template arguments

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

Evening all.  So I have this C++ function I need to call in ObjectiveC which I believe returns some sensor data.  I know every little about C++  I get the following error "Use of class template 'ReadValues' requires template arguments".

How do I call this and how do I access the returned data?

```
template <UBYTE NumValues = 1>
struct ReadValues
{
    const UBYTE code = opINPUT_DEVICE;
    const CUTiny subcode =  READY_SI;
    CLayer layer;
    CInputPort port = OutputPort::A;
    CUTiny type = TYPE_KEEP;
    CMode mode = MODE_KEEP;
    const CUTiny numValues = NumValues;
    using Result = ArrayResult<VarScope::global, ULONG, NumValues>;
};
```

Error

```
ReadValues sensor;
```

The function that I pass ReadValues in to

```
template <typename...  Opcodes>
    typename DirectCommand<Opcodes...>::Results directCommand(float timeout, Opcodes... opcodes)
    {
        if (auto device = _device.lock())
        {
            if (device->isConnected(_activeTransport))
            {
                return device->messenger().directCommand(_activeTransport, timeout, opcodes...);
            }
        }
        return typename DirectCommand<Opcodes...>::Results();
    }
```

Comment: You haven't shown the line of code that actually produces the error. I would guess it looks something like `ReadValues x;`. Even though there's a default argument, class template still requires angle brackets, as in `ReadValues<> x;`

Comment: Your right, how would I then access the result return in ArrayResult<VarScope::global, ULONG, NumValues>;

Comment: The result of what, returned by whom? There are no functions in the code you show - what is it you wonder how to call?

Comment: Sorry So I believe this function should read sensors from a LEGO EV3.  I thought that the bit that says "using Result = ArrayResult<VarScope::global, ULONG, NumValues>" would return or populate a property I can read

Comment: "This function..." What function? Again, the code you show doesn't declare any functions. The line `using Result = ArrayResult<VarScope::global, ULONG, NumValues>` declares a type named `Result` which is an alias of the type `ArrayResult<VarScope::global, ULONG, NumValues>`. It's just another form of `typedef`, in case you are familiar with the latter.

Comment: Updated is that the correct thing

Comment: `The function that I pass ReadValues in to...` Pass how?